How to give altitude to puck3D in mapbox
I'm currently working on a project using Mapbox, where I've implemented a 3D model puck using the Puck3D class. However, I'm facing issues how can I add altitude or elevation to the model, especially in mountainous areas. I google but no such helpful content found.
 Puck3D(model: Model(
            uri: Bundle.main.url(
                forResource: MapViewModel.MapViewLabels.modelName,
                withExtension: MapViewModel.MapViewLabels.modelExt)!,
            position: [mapVM.longitude, mapVM.latitude],
            orientation: MapViewModel.MapViewLabels.modelOrientation),
               bearing: .heading
        )
        .modelScale([2, 2, 2])

I've tried adjusting the altitude using the setLayerProperty method as follows:
try! self.mapVM.mapProxy?.map?.setLayerProperty(
                    for: "puck-model-layer",
                    property: "model-translation",
                    value: [0,0, 5000])

However, this only seems to change the model's altitude relative to the ground, and it doesn't take into account the actual elevation of the terrain.
Could someone please guide me on how to accurately add altitude/elevation to the 3D model puck so that it adjusts properly based on the terrain elevation, especially in mountainous regions?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
example
